# can import React, but not useState?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am attempting to write a cordova app with ts and react by starting with the boilerplate:
https://github.com/davidgerrard/cordova-react-typescript-webpack-boilerplate

The cloned code works fine, but when I attempt to write my own component I start with a typical:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

It imports React just fine, but tells me

```
Module '"react"' has no exported member 'useState'
```

I am used to react on the web, so is there some different way to do this for cordova?  Or is there something that may need to be configured and/or updated?

Comment: Hooks are only available in React 16.8.0 and up. That repo wants React 16.0.0. Try changing the dependency to a higher version.

Comment: @zero298 Ah!  Of course! I should have thought of that.  Did an "npm update" and everything worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR? User zero298 nailed it.

If you ever get this error it is because you are using an old pre-hooks version of React.

The easiest fix is to simply run "npm upgrade" (or yarn, or whatever your preferred package manager is)

I hope others googling this error can learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

For me, there was a mismatch between my `react` version (`17.0.2`) and my `@types/react` version (`17.0.37`). Installing the same version of types solved my issue.

```sh
npm i --save-dev @types/react@17.0.2
```